# Python input text to randomly changed element without id or name

Tags: python

How can I input a text to a span element which is changing randomly at every page load?

I want to write a text on facebook with python but fb is changing span class etc to random at every page load...

If you load https://www.facebook.com/messages page the message input "Aa" is empty... and the element is the message is: `<br data-text="true">`

[image: first]

but if you write something it changes to: `<span data-text="true">test message</span>`

[image: second]

I tried:

```
message_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("br[data-text='true']")
message_input.send_keys('test message')
```

but ofc it makes no sense... not working.

Is there any way I can put text in that span element without importing anything?

Comment: Why are you using `br` in your selector if you are searching for a `span` element?

Comment: Oh and send_keys is for elements that one can type text into.

Comment: Because there is no `span` element until you don't write anything in the "message box" ... it changes dinamically to `span` element from `br` if you write something

Comment: But a br element is just to introduce a line break. It does not allow you to type into it.